# ID посетителя сайта в одноклассниках без clickjacking?

Tags: javascript, одноклассники

Совсем недавно я занимался таким же вопросом по ВКонтакте. Там без clickjacking'a никак, но вот все сервисы уже на правдивом уровне в личном кабинете утверждают, что есть возможность без перехвата клика узнавать ID посетителя сайта в одноклассниках. Подскажите, пожалуйста, знатоки API Одноклассники, возможно через API? Или есть какая микролазейка?

Answer (score 1):

Дорогие коллеги!
Проблема решается очень просто:
1. Создайте левый аккаунт в одноклассниках
2. Создайте приложение и получите долговечный токен
3. Получайте гостей по API, а на сайте через теневой айфрейм получайте информацию о своих посетителях. У меня всё.